# Right align custom OL markers dynamically

Tags: html, css

Is there a way I can get the equivalent of this without hard-coding the noted `margin-left`?

```css
ol.a {
 list-style-type: none;
 counter-reset: item;
 display: inline-block;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 5px;
 border: 1px solid black;  
}
ol.a li {
 counter-increment: item;
 margin-left: 40px; /* How can I avoid this being hard-coded? */
}
ol.a li::before {
 content: '#' counter(item) ':';
 position: absolute;
 margin-left: -1000px; /* These are hard too, but they can be ridiculously large with no problem (as long as I don't want to apply a background I suppose..) */
 width: 995px;
 display: block;
 text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<ol class="a">
 <li>Example</li>
 <li>Example</li>
 <li style="counter-reset: item 9">Example</li>
 <li>Example</li>
 <li style="counter-reset: item 99">Example</li>
 <li>Example</li>
</ol>
```

This works fine with numbers up to 3 digits, but going beyond that I have to manually increase the width for every extra digit. Ideally I could have something that sizes according to the largest item number.

Comment: check the second snippet of the accepted answer

Comment: I wish I had worded my question better, I might have found that post first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace your style with this:

```css
  ol.a {
     list-style-type: none;
     counter-reset: item;
     margin: 0;
     padding: 5px;
     display: table;
     table-layout: fixed;
     border: 1px solid black;
 }
 ol.a li {
     counter-increment: item;
     display: table-row;
 }
 ol.a li::before {
     content: '#'counter(item) ':';
     text-align: right;
     display: table-cell;
     padding: 0 10px;
 }
```